# Loading css via https on a particular page

Tags: css, .htaccess, https

I would like to load a css file via https; however, the javascript console states the css file has been requested via http. I have the following.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//mywebsite.com/Bold/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//mywebsite.com/Book/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
```

Is there another way to approach this so I could fetch the css via https on the specific page?

Comment: that would request the css through https if the site is loaded over https.

Comment: +Brett looks like your message got messed up

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the css file without the host name. Then browser will use the page's original protocol.

```
/Bold/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I get Failed to load resource with a 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: Here's a full link: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/x.css">. Perhaps there is something else going on.